# Python code and modelbuilder

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, query

I am working with ArcGIS 10.2 and using python to use the function for zoom to selected feature.  I need to have this zoom to selected feature work for any project and I also need drop down menus for all of the SQL's (Quarter section, township, range, and meridian) that I currently have.

```
#Zoom to Selected Feature in SearchMap Dataframe

import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
df.scale = df.scale * 1.1

# Clear selections on the Southern Reference Grid layer DataFrame

clearLyrs = ["Southern Reference Grid"]
for clearLyr in clearLyrs:
    lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, clearLyr, df)[0]
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "CLEAR_SELECTION")

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Without a question mark, it is very hard to discern the question that you are asking.  Would you be able to use the **edit** button beneath your question to revise it with this and additional details like whether you are trying to write a Python script tool, a Python Toolbox, a Python AddIn, or something else, please?